# Деепричастие (пунктуация и употребление)

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Возникло два вопроса, но, как мне показалось, они достаточно мелкие, чтобы спрашивать по отдельности. Есть такие предложения (не обращайте внимание/не трогайте формулировку первого, пожалуйста):

1. Имя его друга отозвалось приятными воспоминаниями, вызывая улыбку на лице (человек вспомнил друга, и это вызвало улыбку на лице).

Правильно ли использован деепричастный оборот? По идее, действие совершает само имя, а не в отношении него. Допустимо ли использовать деепричастия (одиночные или обороты), если основное действие стоит в возвратной форме (если конструкция не страдательная и подлежащее в именительном падеже - это важно!)?

2. К нему подбежал друг, который () опершись о стену () пытался перевести дух.

Как по мне, это просто добавочное действие, т.е. должно быть так:

К нему подбежал друг, который, опершись о стену, начал переводить дух.

Правильна ли такая расстановка знаков? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ну так имя и отозвалось, и вызвало. Нет ограничений на возвратные глаголы. Только вот форма и время у деепричастий разные, слову "отозвалось" соответствует "вызвав".

> если конструкция не страдательная

Страдательные нельзя.

> Как по мне, это просто добавочное действие, т.е. должно быть так

Да, верно. Ну что плохо? Такое придаточное не очень корректно. Продолжаем мысль за счёт него. Будто было несколько друзей, а подбежал именно тот, который начал переводить дух. Надо так:
*К нему подбежал друг и, опершись о стену, начал переводить дух.*
"Который" для того, чтобы сказать, что за друг, а не что он потом делал.
И об этом стоит говорить. Не раз замечал такое неверное употребление.
Похожий пример:
*Мы купили лимон, который потом использовали в приготовлении пирога.* || Но ведь не было никакого пирога, когда покупали.

Comment: Правила есть такие: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Comment: А то получается следующее: *Мы купили лимон, (какой именно лимон купили?) который использовали в приготовлении пирога.*

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастие относится к подлежащему ‟который”. Правильная пунктуация такая: ‟К нему подбежал друг, который, опершись о стену, начал переводить дух”. В справочнике Розенталя есть пункт про отсутствии запятой в определительных придаточных где союзное слово не является подлежащим, как в предложении:‟Вышло много игр, играя в которые можно получить удовольствие”; но ваше предложение не такого типа.